# React-- Timer begins counting seconds in the click of a button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, intervals

I am building a small game with React and I am set to include a countdown timer on it.

There are many tutorials (including one in React's official documentation) on how to create a timer or countdown timer with React. All of them however use the `componentDidMount` and `componentWillUnmount` lifecycle methods to set and respectively clear the interval.

This works fine, but the timer starts counting the moment the component mounts. I d like to have a timer that starts counting onClick.

What are the appropriate lifecycle methods to achieve such a behavior? I ve already tried `componentWillUpdate` and `componentDidUpdate` but to no effect.

My first thought was to use a gameOn state property in order to activate the timer only when game is on (ie the start button has been pressed) but this did not work because (I guess) I am setting gameOn to true, long after the component didMount.

I have also tried to move these two methods along with appropriate state ({secondsElapsed: 0}) on the Timer component, since Timer is a seperate component that communicates with its parent through props. This too had no luck.

Finally I tried setting `this.interval = null;` on my constructor function but this had no difference on the way the Timer is functioning.

I am thinking that the root of the issue is the lifecycle methods because these control when the setInterval and clearInterval will be called. So my question is this:

***Which other combo of lifecycle methods should I use to achieve the behavior I am after?***

Any well versed suggestions will be appreciated.

**Bonus points if you can explain in clear terms on why and when should I declare `this.interval = null;` on my constructor function.**

For an example of what I have so far, really basically look at the "[A Stateful Component](https://facebook.github.io/react/)"

Comment: You can always start an interval any way you want just dont forget to clear them. In react life cycle, the best place to clean things is during `componentWillUnmount`. Why? Because you want to be sure that the interval is cleared all the time.

Comment: Wait, wont this be the case with componentDidUpdate as well?

Comment: that would be not an ideal place to put it because there are many factors that a component updates. Probably you want it to be trigger/cleared by an event(onClick) or during unmount.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
componentWillUnmount() {
  clearInterval(this.interval); // Always clean up before unmounting
}

render(){
  <div>
    <button
      onClick={() => { this.interval = setInterval(() => {
        // Do something here e.g. increment the time
        // NOTE: `this` keyword here refers to the component itself
      }, 1000); }}>
      Start
    </button>
  </div>
}
```

Comment: The problem here is that the onClick function is on the parent component, but I d like to refer to the Timer component when it comes to componentWillUnmount()... I have four components (main, start, action and timer). main is the parent of start and start the parent of action and timer.

Comment: Can you explain further what properties you what to be accessed, where should it be accessed, and from where?

Comment: This actually worked. I did not know it was possible to set this.interval from the onClick function. Should have thought about it but this insistence of tutorials on using it with lifecycle methods disoriented me. Kudos!

Comment: btw do you know any specific reason why use this.interval=null; on the constructor function? Some general info on the interval property would be nice. (Google search havent brought anything too helpful).